# "pip3 list" not showing any output on terminal when using WSL

Tags: python, pip, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Tried to do a `pip3 install virtualenv` and found that there are no outputs and have left the terminal to run for quite some time. Have to do a manual interruption using Ctrl+C. Tried other commands which are pip-related, such as `pip3 list` and it also does not show any outputs.

[terminal showing pip3 list command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpGnq.png)

Have tried to do a clean pip3 reinstallation by following https://askubuntu.com/questions/1180940/how-do-i-perform-a-full-reinstallation-of-pip-and-pip3. Still the result is the same.

May I know how to resolve this issue? Should I make a new clean version of WSL VM?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  A few questions (edit your question with the additional info, please) - (1) Windows 10 or 11?  (2) Do you have a `DISPLAY` variable set?  If so, try unsetting it.  (3) Have you done any special customizations to your WSL such as running Systemd or GUI apps (under Windows 10)?  Not a problem necessarily, if you have, but might give us a clue as to where to look.

Answer (score 1):

NotTheDro01ds comment is correct:

`pip` breaks if a `DISPLAY` variable is set and the XServer is not running.

- Solution 1: start the XServer
- Solution 2: remove the `DISPLAY` variable